# The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size, even after increasing buffer pool size

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, memory, mysql-5.1

I am trying to partition a table with 200 million records in it. This table already exists:

```
CREATE TABLE linkmap_ntoken (
  target_nToken varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  ntoken_hashcode int(15) NOT NULL,
  targeturl varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  targetbreadcrumb varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  sourceurl varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  sourcebreadcrumb varchar(400) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB.
```

Now I am trying to create 500 partition with this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE linkmap_ntoken partition by HASH (ntoken_hashcode) partitions 500;
```

It throws exception: total number of locks exceeded the lock table size.

I read few suggestions online and changed `my.cnf` file. Here are the configurations:

```
# PER CLIENT SETTINGS #
# bit high but I got tons of ram here #
sort_buffer_size                = 2M
read_buffer_size                = 2M
binlog_cache_size               = 1M
wait_timeout                    = 31536000
interactive_timeout             = 300
max_allowed_packet              = 12M
thread_stack                    = 128K
table_cache                     = 1024
myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 1M
tmp_table_size                  = 12M
max_heap_table_size             = 12M


# LOGGING #
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/slowquery.log

# MyISAM #
key_buffer_size                = 32M
myisam_recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000


# BINARY LOGGING #
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days               = 14
sync_binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 2048

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 40G
```

I have restarted mysql after making these changes. Still it throws the exception. My server has 12 cores and 48GB Ram and I can dedicate this server for this partitioning process for time being. Are there any suggestions to bypass this exception (total number of locks exceeded)?

When I did show global variables, it is showing buffer pool size as 8388608. I changed `innodb_buffer_pool_size` under `[mysqld]` block and restarted. It doesn't seems to be affected. It is still 8388608.

Regarding "why partitioning", I do not have a unique column to have a primary key. Even If I add one I won't be able to query with it. I am using this table to query for an online application. I want my query to return results in less than a second.

Comment: Have you tried to change `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 80M`? It worked for me.

Comment: Please post your complete error log and complete my.cnf/ini.  Having 48GB RAM is good, what is your max_connections variable set at?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in my.cnf file,

[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 80M

And you need to restart the Workbench as well as the Sql service.

Comment: It clearly states `innodb-buffer-pool-size = 40G` in the post.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a late answer, but should someone experience a similar problem in the future, remember that the solution lies in tweaking the Innodb_buffer_pool_size. This of course assumes that your server is a dedicated mysql database server. By default, it is a good practice to give it 10% more that the actual memory size that the server has. MySQL is able to slowly scale up usage of buffer_pool and will give your tables good performance on CRUD actions.